# Sci-Fi Book from the 1980's - feline race protects a blue flame

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to locate a book that I read in the 1980s.

- It was about a feline race that protected a blue flame.
- If the flame went out this would result in the death of humanity(?).
- The space travelling felines could talk.

I am hoping someone may have read it and remember the title. Thank you.

Comment: Why were they protecting a blue flame?

Comment: To protect the human race. If the flame went out then humanity died.

Comment: http://anthrozine.com/site/lbry/cat.novels1.html